# Error during incremental learning with LSTM model training a MIDI music generation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, midi

I'm working on a MIDI music generation project using Python and TensorFlow. After training my LSTM model on a set of MIDI files, I'm encountering an 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error during model training with 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' loss. The error message states that it received a label value outside the valid range:

The software **only works when training a new model.**
The issue is when I want to do incremental learning.

It works for a few seconds but then:

*W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at sparse_xent_op.cc:103 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Received a label value of 70 which is outside the valid range of [0, 70).  Label values: 6 51 22 57 55 9 53 23 5 67 9 46 37 36 49 58 67 49 33 56 9 13 26 6 25 25 9 52 38 31 70 57*

> Code snippet where the error resides:

```
def incremental_train_model():
global training_dir, sequences, model

if not training_dir:
    print("Please select the training files directory.")
    return
if not sequences:
    print("Please train the model first.")
    return

# Convert MIDI files to music21 stream objects
training_files = [os.path.join(training_dir, file) for file in os.listdir(training_dir) if file.endswith((".mid", ".musicxml"))]
for file in training_files:
    midi = converter.parse(file)
    notes = []
    chords = []
    for element in midi.flatten():
        if isinstance(element, note.Note):
            notes.append(str(element.pitch))
        elif isinstance(element, chord.Chord):
            notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))
    sequences.append(notes)

# Create input and output sequences
sequence_length = 100
pitch_names = sorted(set(note for sequence in sequences for note in sequence))
note_to_int = dict((note, number) for number, note in enumerate(pitch_names))
network_input = []
network_output = []
for sequence in sequences:
    for i in range(len(sequence) - sequence_length):
        sequence_in = sequence[i:i + sequence_length]
        sequence_out = sequence[i + sequence_length]
        network_input.append([note_to_int[char] for char in sequence_in])
        network_output.append(note_to_int[sequence_out])
n_classes = len(pitch_names)
network_output = np.array([label % n_classes for label in network_output])
n_patterns = len(network_input)

# Check if network_input is empty
if n_patterns == 0:
    print("No training sequences found.")
    return

# Reshape the input
network_input = np.reshape(network_input, (n_patterns, sequence_length, 1))
network_input = network_input / float(len(pitch_names))

# Check if the pretrained model exists, if not create a new model
if not model:
    # Create the model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(network_input.shape[1], network_input.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(LSTM(256))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(len(pitch_names), activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    print("New model created.")

# Train the model incrementally
print("Incremental training started...")
model.fit(network_input, network_output, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
print("Incremental training completed.")

# Save the updated sequences
np.save(os.path.join(model_dir, "sequences.npy"), sequences)
print("Sequences saved successfully.")
```